# How to add DOB in guest checkout page?

Tags: magento2, guest-checkout

Is there any way to show DOB (Date Of Birth) field in guest checkout page?

I saw [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200844/magento-2-how-to-add-date-of-birth-and-gender-fields-in-checkout/221708?noredirect=1#comment327172_221708), but with it we have to create and set the dob field in quote with InstallSchema.php file, and I know that customers have DOB field, and in `Stores > Config > Sales > Customers >Name and Address Options` there's an option to show DOB field, is there any way to use this field instead to create a new one?

Thanks in advance.